# UITableViewRowAction not working on Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, prism

When i am trying to delete a row in table view by swiping left, Swipe is not working. Sometimes after 10-12 attempts, table view row swipes and then i am able to see delete button. Below is the code i am using. Please let me know where i am doing it wrong ?

Note: Issue is occurring on iPhone's. On iPad's everything works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Controls;
using Project.Events;
using Project.Models;
using Foundation;
using Prism.Autofac;
using Prism.Events;
using Prism.Ioc;
using UIKit;

namespace Project.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class ExtendedListViewMPSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        IList<PlaylistModel> tableItems;
        ExtendedListViewMP listView;

        public IEnumerable<PlaylistModel> Items
        {
            //get{ }
            set => tableItems = value.ToList();
        }

        public ExtendedListViewMPSource(ExtendedListViewMP view)
        {
            tableItems = (IList<PlaylistModel>)view.Items.ToList();
            listView = view;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the TableView to determine how many cells to create for that particular section.
        /// </summary>
        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return tableItems.Count;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called by the TableView to get the actual UITableViewCell to render for the particular section and row
        /// </summary>
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            // Request a recycled cell to save memory, if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (!(tableView.DequeueReusableCell(PlaylistViewCell.Key) is PlaylistViewCell cell))
            {
                cell = new PlaylistViewCell(PlaylistViewCell.Key);
                var views = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("PlaylistViewCell", cell, null);
                cell = ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject(views.ValueAt(0)) as PlaylistViewCell;
            }

            var item = tableItems[indexPath.Row];
            cell.UpdateCellAsync(item);

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var model = tableItems[indexPath.Row];

            if (listView.ListViewSelectionMode == ExtendedListViewSelectionMode.Multiple)
            {
                model.Selected = !model.Selected;
                NSIndexPath[] indexPaths = { indexPath };
                tableView.ReloadRows(indexPaths, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
            }

            listView.NotifyItemSelected(model);
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        }

        public override UITableViewRowAction[] EditActionsForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewRowAction deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction.Create(
                UITableViewRowActionStyle.Destructive,
                "Delete",
                    DeleteRowActionHandler
                ); 

            return new UITableViewRowAction[] { deleteButton };
        }

        private void DeleteRowActionHandler(UITableViewRowAction rowAction, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current is PrismApplication prismApplication)
            {
                var eventAggregator = prismApplication.Container.Resolve<IEventAggregator>();
                if (eventAggregator != null)
                {
                    var playlistId = tableItems[indexPath.Row].Id;
                    eventAggregator.GetEvent<PlaylistDeleteEvent>().Publish(
                        new PlaylistDeleteEventParameters(playlistId, true, listView.ItemPlaylistType)
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your project a Xamarin.forms project or a Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: You code looks well. Is there any swipegesture in your PlaylistViewCell?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : Actually Master Detail Page swipe gesture is enable . Disabling it works. Is there any way we can disable Master Detail Page Swipe gesture only on this page ??

Comment: Disable it in the Page's [OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method and enable it  in [OnDisappearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.ondisappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @JackHua-MSFT

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT : Please look at the answer below. That is what i did and its working when User navigates from Master Detail page. Now what if user doesn't navigate from Master Detail page. and if page loads directly after Sign in ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            if ((Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage) != null)
            {
                (Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage).IsGestureEnabled = false;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now what if user doesn't navigate from Master Detail page. and if
>   page loads directly after Sign in

`OnAppearing` method and  `OnDisappearing` will always fire when a page becoming visible or a page disappears. Page loads by Navigate or loads directly after Sign in will both work.

What you need to do is Disable it in the Page's OnAppearing method and enable it in OnDisappearing method as I mentioned in the comment.

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    if ((Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage) != null)
    {
        (Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage).IsGestureEnabled = false;
    }
}

protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    if ((Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage) != null)
    {
        (Application.Current.MainPage as MainMasterDetailPage).IsGestureEnabled = true;
    }
}
```